# Changing Text of a Sticky Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Sticky text on the left side of the screen.I want to change the text as soon as user scroll to a certain section.Like on initial load i want to display home, and after the user scroll to about section the text changes to about.
Till now i have used state and window scrollY.But using this my site performance is degraded.
I know i am not using the effect hook efficiently.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import DrawerToggleButton from "../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton";
import "./Tracer.css";

const Tracer = props => {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
  const [offsetValue, setOffsetValue] = useState(0);
  const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState("Home");

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setOffsetValue(window.pageYOffset);
}
    });
  });
  const text =
    offsetValue > 285 ? "About" : offsetValue > 627 ? "Skills" : "Home";
  console.log("scorllOffser", offsetValue);
  return (
    <div>
      <header className={"toolbar2"}>
        <nav className="toolbar__navigation2">
          <div className="toolbar__logo2">
            <h1>{currentText}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="spacer" />
        </nav>
      </header>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tracer;
```

I tried different variations, and even got the result but performance is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your useEffect is called for every update and therefore you are calling addEventListener a lot of times. This will definitively degrade the performance of your app. You should only call addEventListener once and also removeEventListener before unmounting the component. Add this to do both only once:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // adding event listener on mount here
   return () => {
       // cleaning up the listener here
   }
}, []);
```

The important part is the [] at the end which will make useEffect trigger only once

Answer (score 1):

Although all answers may be the same, [you should `throttle` or `debounce` your listener:](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

```
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

useEffect(() => {
  const listener = debounce(() => {
    setOffsetValue(window.pageYOffset);
  }, 1000);
  document.addEventListener("scroll", debounce(listener, 1000));
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", listener);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Can you edit the answer to have the debounce call around the `const listener` declaration? Otherwise the listener won't be correct to remove the listener on cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cleanup the event listener in your effect and also add a dependency array on the effect.

Although scroll events are famous for having a TON of events, so I'd suggest to debounce/throttle the listener as well. I usually use lodash's [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) for that.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import DrawerToggleButton from '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton';
import './Tracer.css';

const Tracer = (props) => {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
  const [offsetValue, setOffsetValue] = useState(0);
  const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState('Home');

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = () => {
      setOffsetValue(window.pageYOffset);
    };
    document.addEventListener('scroll', listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', listener);
    };
  }, []);
  const text = offsetValue > 285 ? 'About' : offsetValue > 627 ? 'Skills' : 'Home';
  console.log('scorllOffser', offsetValue);
  return (
    <div>
      <header className={'toolbar2'}>
        <nav className="toolbar__navigation2">
          <div className="toolbar__logo2">
            <h1>{currentText}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="spacer" />
        </nav>
      </header>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tracer;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am newbie.Just have a question if we are using this useEffect as componentDidMount, which basically runs once when the component is mounted.How come the eventListner is called again and again?

Comment: useEffect and any other hook with a dependency array is triggered any time a value in the dependency array changes (by shallow equality). If you have an empty array, it's triggered on mount only and then cleaned up on unmount. If you don't have a dependency array at all, then the hook is triggered every render instead.

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect hook requires a an array or object of dependencies, otherwise it will run in an infinite loop. You can put an array containing a piece of state to run it on state change.

You need to set a piece of state (I would just make a piece of state that contains a string with the current section title ) and set that as a dependency.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setOffsetValue(window.pageYOffset);
}
    }, [<Your State here>]);
```

You can also set it to run on DOM load by putting an empty pair of brackets in the argument list.